# How to work with $http.jsonp

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp, angular-http

**I am using below code to get json data i ma getting success ,200 status and repsonse in network tab of browser (developer tools)
then i have put break point then its going to error and i ma gettinf 404 status and undefined data can you please help me in this**

```
var url = 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8084/api/users/current/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
       $http.jsonp(url,{ withCredentials: true})
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);


    })
    .error(function(data) {

        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: why `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK`?

Comment: And what do you get as a response? What is the error logged?

Comment: @JB Nizet my response is
"testUser"
console.log(error);--->In log  i am getting data ="" status=404